# How to collect multiple asynchronous results with JQuery AJAX call to MVC app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I want to be able to log a series of events when doing some server side background work in an MVC web app. Basically, I currently have a JQuery AJAX call triggering my server side action. While asynchronous, the action only returns data once, when it has completed (of if an exception is thrown for example). I need to log the messages on the client side as they generated on the server side.

Considering this, is there a way that I could post multiple log messages to my calling site while the work is still being done on the server side ? Would an AJAX push be the only way considering I am already in the context of an ajax GET/POST ? Is there a way not only to have an asynchronous GET/POST, but to get back asynchronous results through that same call using JQUery ?

Comment: Don't use ajax for this. Use Web sockets, Server sent events or something like that for pushing log messages to the client - and ajax long polling as a fallback.

Comment: Any code to show what you have tried?